# Speed up rate of transfer data in RelayTCP

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, winsock2

I am building a program has features as RelayTCP.
Its responsibility is forward data between Client and Server.

Client <----> RelayTCP <-----> Server

The below codes belong to RelayTCP when forward data.

```
char *buff = new char[BUF_MAX];
int recvLength = 0;
int sendLength = 0;

recvLength = recv(inSock, buff, BUF_MAX, 0);
buff[recvLength] = '\0';

sendLength = send(outSock, buff, recvLength, 0);

delete buff;
```

although I set BUF_MAX very big (ex: BUF_MAX = 4096000), but Client sends data to Server very slowly. I tried to set socket option TCP_NODELAY to speed up, but not succeed

However, in the case Client connects directly to Server. the speed of transferring data is very high.

Please tell me why using RelayTCP the speed of transferring data is very slow.

**--------------new information---------------**

Sorry all about i posted not enough information.
Actually, my project has two programs : Parent and Child.

Parent will wait connection from Client, after accept, it connects to Server. After that it generates Child process. Child process inherits two sockets of Parent.

Parent.cpp

```
ownAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
ownAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
ownAddr.sin_port = htons(49280);

listenSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

bind(listenSock, (SOCKADDR *)&ownAddr, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));

listen(listenSock, 5);

inSock = accept(listenSock, 0, 0);

BOOL bOpt = TRUE;
    setsockopt(inSock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *)&bOpt, sizeof(bOpt));

serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.44.131");
serverAddr.sin_port = htons(22);

outSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

connect(outSock, (SOCKADDR *)&serverAddr, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));

setsockopt(outSock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *)&bOpt, sizeof(bOpt));

STARTUPINFO startInfo = {0};
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo = {0};

TCHAR cmd[1024] = {0};
TCHAR buff[1024];

GetCurrentDirectory(1024, buff);

wsprintf(cmd, _T("\"%s\\RelayTCP.exe\""), buff);

ZeroMemory(buff, 1024);
wsprintf(buff, _T(" %d %d"), inSock, outSock);
_tcscat(cmd, buff);

CreateProcess(NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &startInfo, &processInfo);
```

Child.cpp

```
WSAEVENT eventArray[2];
SOCKET sockArray[2];
int result = 0;

sockArray[0] = (SOCKET)_tstoi(argv[1]);
sockArray[1] = (SOCKET)_tstoi(argv[2]);

WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    eventArray[i] = WSACreateEvent();
    WSAEventSelect(sockArray[i], eventArray[i], FD_READ | FD_WRITE | FD_CLOSE);
}

DWORD index = 0;
WSANETWORKEVENTS networkEvent;
while(TRUE)
{
    index = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(eventTotal, eventArray, FALSE, WSA_INFINITE, FALSE);
    index = index - WSA_WAIT_EVENT_0;

    for (int i = index; i < eventTotal; i++)
    {
        index = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(1, &eventArray[i], TRUE, 1000, FALSE);
        if (index == WSA_WAIT_FAILED || index == WSA_WAIT_TIMEOUT)
        {
            continue;
        }
        index = i;
        WSAResetEvent(eventArray[index]);
        WSAEnumNetworkEvents(sockArray[index], eventArray[index], &networkEvent);

        if (networkEvent.lNetworkEvents & FD_READ)
        {
            char *buff = new char[BUF_MAX];
            int recvLength = 0;
            int sendLength = 0;

            recvLength = recv(sockArray[index], buff, BUF_MAX, 0);
            buff[recvLength] = '\0';

            sendLength = send(sockArray[1 - index], buff, recvLength, 0);

            printf("recvLength = %d, sendLength = %d\n", recvLength, sendLength);

            delete [] buff;
        }

        if (networkEvent.lNetworkEvents & FD_WRITE)
        {
            // do nothing
        }

        if (networkEvent.lNetworkEvents & FD_CLOSE)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                closesocket(sockArray[i]);
                WSACloseEvent(eventArray[i]);
            }
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I think we need a little more code. What you have shown us would only send data in one direction and would likely only transfer the first random number of bytes from the inSock to the outSock (based on how many bytes the kernel/winsock library decided to return from your recv call.

Comment: You have to use `delete[] buff` instead of `delete buff`.

Comment: Also, it might be worth noting that what you're writing is called a proxy and probably already exists for whatever you want to do. If you're writing it for fun, great, otherwise it might be best to use something that already exists and has been optimized.

Comment: Without knowing what kind of data is being exchanged between the Client and Server, and in what order, there is no real way for anyone to tell you why it is running so slow.  Maybe you are not calling `recv()` and `send()` often enough. Maybe you are communicating with the Server slowly, so the Client is not getting what it needs from the Server fast enough. There is just not enough code shown to know.

Comment: For high scalability and speed, you might want to look into using I/O Completion Ports instead of inefficient `recv`/`send` loops: [Windows Sockets 2.0: Write Scalable Winsock Apps Using Completion Ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302334.aspx). Create an IOCP for each Client/Server connection pair, then call `WSARecv()` on each connection to begin reading. Whenever the IOCP reports that a read has completed on a connection, call `WSASend()` to pass the read data to the other connection.

Comment: Well, in reality, if he wants to do bidirectional "blind" data transfer he'll need two threads, one for each direction. He could use non-blocking I/O, but that would be even more complicated.

Comment: @CrazyCasta: IOCP is more efficient and uses fewer threads while providing asynchronous transfers in both directions with minimal coding needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I know nothing about that, I was referring to your suggestion that he's not calling recv/send enough. Not only may he not be calling them enough, he may need another whole thread to handle the other direction.

Comment: Dear all, I have add more information of my project. Please help me!